# understanding Frame placement in android ViewGroup sample

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

This question is apropos the [sample found in the official ViewGroup documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).

I cannot figure why the following line is correct

```
mTmpContainerRect.left = rightPos - width - lp.leftMargin;
```

I feel that it should be

```
mTmpContainerRect.left = rightPos - width - lp.leftMargin - lp.rightMargin;
```

Will someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
L' ********* | ***************************** | ************ R'

   L_Margin  L           Width               R    R_Margin
```

L' = R - width - L_Margin

The answer you feel is right would only be correct if R represented the full width including its R margin (R' in my fancy diagram).